# Undefined Symbols in simple C program

Tags: c

New to C can someone tell me what is wrong with this program.

```
    #include <stdio.h>

float volume = 0.00;    
float radius = 10.00;

float calculateSphereVolume(float radiusCubed){
    volume = 4.0f/3.0f * radiusCubed;
    printf("%.2f", volume);

    return volume;
}

int main(void){
    calcuateSphereVolume(radius * radius * radius); 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: typo on calcuateSphereVolume vs. calculateSphereVolume.  Also you'll need a piece of PI ;-)

Comment: Also, design-wise, the function should calculate the cube of the radius; the calling code should not need to do so.  Of course, then you rename the argument as 'radius'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int main(void){
    calcuateSphereVolume(radius * radius * radius); 
    return 0;
}
```

You spelt 'calculateSphereVolume' incorrectly for one...

Also, you need to rethink your formula for the volume of a sphere :Pi

Comment: How does one get Pi, is there a library?

Comment: if you #include <math.h> you can use: double pi = 4.0*atan(1.0);

Comment: or #include <math.h>, and define _USE_MATH_DEFINES.

Comment: Is there a reason no-one has mentioned `#include <math.h>` and using `M_PI`?

Answer (score 2):

Call site and declaration are spelled differently!  Also, I think you're missing a factor of pi in your volume calculation.

Comment: Unless pi has become exactly 1. :X

Comment: @Mark: Extension to non-Euclidean metric spaces left as an exercise for the reader...

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
#define pi = 3.14159265
```

and

```
volume=4.0f/3.0f * pi * radius* radius * radius;
```

Comment: Please don't define constants that are already provided in the standard library (`math.h`), and please don't use `#define` to define constants - use real constants.